# Searching QStringList for specific items and then others that may contains an item

Tags: c++, qt

I want to get all the "INDICES" of a search.  Appearently "QStringList::indexOf" returns one index at a time... so I have to do a while loop.  But it also "only" does exact matches.

What if I want to return all indices of items that possess "husky"... then maybe "dog"... then "dog 2".
Am I stuck with than "QString::contains" and then loop, to accomplish this?  Or is there a more "QStringList class" related way that I am missing

```
QStringList dogPound;
dogPound    << "husky dog 1"
            << "husky dog 2"
            << "husky dog 2 spotted"
            << "lab dog 2 spotted";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `QStringList::filter` method. It returns a new `QStringList` containing all the items that pass from a filter.

```
QStringList dogPound;
dogPound    << "husky dog 1"
            << "husky dog 2"
            << "husky dog 2 spotted"
            << "lab dog 2 spotted";

QStringList spotted = dogPound.filter("spotted");
// spotted now contains "husky dog 2 spotted" and "lab dog 2 spotted"
```

Comment: I think for simplicity, to get the index, it is easier to just use "QStringList::contains" in a loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you are so hesitant about a loop. You need to write a loop to iterate over the indices as i understand, so why not combine two loops together and use 'contains' or 'filter'?

Comment: The looping was the only way I knew of, I wasn't sure if their was something more inherit to the class that I was missing... ie:  "filter" returns the items, but maybe there is a flag to set to return the indices.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the most straight forward approach of finding the position of a specific QString in a QStringList:

```
#include <algorithm>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QStringList words;
    words.append("bar");
    words.append("baz");
    words.append("fnord");

    QStringList search;
    search.append("fnord");
    search.append("bar");
    search.append("baz");
    search.append("bripiep");

    foreach(const QString &word, search)
    {
        int i = -1;
        QStringList::iterator it = std::find(words.begin(), words.end(), word);
        if (it != words.end())
            i = it - words.begin();

        qDebug() << "index of" << word << "in" << words << "is" << i;
    }

    return 0;
}
```